# DoubleRenderError in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a `ProjectsController` for which all the actions except `new` and `index` are restricted to `admins`. I have added a before_filter in my controller like

```
before_action :authorize_admin!, except: [:index, :show]
```

and the `before_filter` looks like this.

```
def authorize_admin!
  check_login!

  unless current_user.admin?
    redirect_to root_path, alert: "You're not authorized"
  end
end
```

`check_login!` is a method in `ApplicationController` which redirects to the `root_path` is the user's not logged in.

```
def check_login!
  flash[:alert] =  'You need to sign up or sign in before continuing'
  redirect_to login_path unless current_user
end
```

`current_user` is a method which returns a user record if a session for user exists.(Its not relevant to the error)

The problem is when I try to access `/projects/4/edit` without logging in, I am getting an `undefined method`admin?' for nil:NilClass`error. In the before filter,`check_login!`is executed first and if the user's not logged in, he should be redirected to the`root_path`. This clearly means that even after redirect, the execution is not terminated.

In the web console, I tried to execute `check_login!` and this time, I got  an `AbstractController::DoubleRenderError: Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action.` error. And it hinted me to use `redirect_to(..) and return`.

Although I knew it won't work, I tried modifying my `check_login?` method to

```
def check_login!
  redirect_to login_path, alert:
    'You need to sign up or sign in before continuing' and return unless current_user
end
```

And I also tried the following after looking at a SO thread.

```
return redirect_to login_path, alert:
    'You need to sign up or sign in before continuing` unless current_user
```

I assume that it fails cause it returns to the callee, the `authorize_admin!` method and again as the current_user is nil, I get the `undefined method` error.

How can I solve this issue?

Note: I don't want to repeat the `check_login!` code in `authorize_admin!` as it violates DRY.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a filter redirects then subsequent filters and the action itself do not run, but the filter itself continues. In your case, after `check_login!` is called, the `authorize_admin!` filter continues executing.

You could change `check_login!` to return true if the check passed and false if there is no current user. Then `authorize_admin` could do

```
check_login! || return
```

Alternatively, the `performed?` method tells you if a render or redirect has occurred so you could do

```
check_login!
return if performed?
```